# can a derived class change the protected members of its indirect base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Class B inherits publicly class A, and class C inherits publicly class B.

1) My question is can class C make changes to protected data members of class A ?

2) Also I believe that class C can access the protected and public components of class B but can it also access the same of class A ?

To sum it up what is the relationship between the derived class (C) and its indirect base class (A) ? I couldn't find any in depth answers to this online..

Comment: What did you observe when you tried it out?

Comment: You can try this out, it's just like 20 strings of C++ code. If you'll be having troubles with such code, we'll be happy to help.